# External authentication via LDAP

Tags: ldap, marklogic

I am doing external authentication using LDAP. I have to authenticate a user via LDAP and allow the user to access many app servers. I want to know how to map all the ldap user ( users in ldap server Example:ldap://company1.local:389) with users in Database. I have created a external configuration object and assigned to a new http server with application level authentication. I dont want to store ldap user password in database. Do I have to create all users(same as in active directory) in database with some password and map them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to configure ML to use external authentication via LDAP:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/external-auth

Comment: I have followed all the steps.  Http server port is 8020. When I go to localhost:8020, I entered user credentials and I get 404 not found. How LDAP map the database user with external names to ldap server?

Comment: @Ajaii Are you sure ML is able to connect to LDAP? Does localhost:8020 prompt for credentials, or did you just enter them as part of the URL?

Comment: yes I can connect to ldap server. I used xdmp:ldap-lookup for checking one user. It displayed all the details of user. When I go to  localhost:8020,it prompts for credentials. I entered username and password. I got 404 error. I am using Active Directory Explorer to see all users and I store the same username with external names.Do I have to create any roles for the users?

Comment: Sort of. You need to associate LDAP groups with ML roles. See: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/security/external-auth#id_34690

Comment: In my case, some users are present in different location, For example 10 users in Uk, 10 users in france. Can you explain me how to create LDAP groups and associate it to Marklogic roles?

Comment: @Ajaii To create a group in AD see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa545347(v=cs.70).aspx. To associate a group with a ML role, see the above documentation.

Comment: Sorry. My question is how to associate LDAP groups to ML roles.       I created a ldap role separately for UK and France location with ML roles and assigned ldap role to Users. Now when I enter user credentials,I can see Marklogic Rest Server Page. For some users, I get error.     <rapi:status-code>403</rapi:status-code><rapi:status>Forbidden</rapi:status>                   <rapi:message-code>SEC-PRIV<>You do not have permission to this method and URL

Comment: @Ajaii Could be wrong, but to my knowledge MarkLogic first checks authentication. Only after that it starts looking for the requested resource. So, getting a 404 would mean that authentication succeeded. Are you sure you are accessing an existing resource? Module, image, default.xqy or other?

Comment: @grtjn: you are right.Authentication is checked and then it looks for resource. But I get this error when I enter my username and password(problem only with my username). Do I have to include any privilege(security privilege). Other users are working and checked the current user using xdmp:get-current-user()(default.xqy).  I use my username to connect to VPN and I have entered my username details as a default user in the External Security configuration object.

Comment: @Ajaii I'm not very familiar with the LDAP support, but in general a MarkLogic user needs to have the right to execute xqy, and read docs. If your troubling user pre-exists in ML, try disabling LDAP, set the user as default with app-level authentication. If there is still a problem, your problem is related to document/module permissions. Give your user a role that is allowed to exec the resource you are calling. Compare the roles of that user with those of the other users you have..

Comment: @grtjn: the problem is user does not have permission to access document/module. I have set my username and password as default user.

Comment: @Ajaii Your ML user doesn't have permission? Or some other user? As `grtjn` explained, confirm that ML users/roles have the correct permissions/exec privileges. Then proceed to map roles to LDAP groups. If you have a problem there, then you have at least isolated the problem to mapping, not ML security configuration.

Comment: @wst:The error after entering my credentials is <rapi:error xmlns:rapi="http://marklogic.com/rest-api">
<rapi:status-code>403</rapi:status-code>
<rapi:status>Forbidden</rapi:status>
<rapi:message-code>SEC-PRIV</rapi:message-code>
<rapi:message>You do not have permission to this method and URL</rapi:message>
</rapi:error>. I checked user roles with other roles.It is same as the other users.Default user(my username) defined in external security is used only if authentication is  kerberos and authorization is ldap.

Comment: @Ajaii If you are entering ML credentials directly and getting 403, then your ML user is missing an execution privilege. If other users are able to access that endpoint, then I suggest you look again at the security configuration. It will also help to read `ErrorLog.txt` to determine specifically which privilege is needed.

Comment: @wst : I am not missing any execution privilege. The configuration are same as other users. I even assigned admin role and admin role.which privilege i should assign?

Comment: @Ajaii Are you saying that if you enter the credentials of an admin user directly to the ML REST endpoint you receive an error? Or are you still trying to use LDAP? Also, what specific error are you seeing in the log?

Comment: I am trying to use LDAP. Now i unchecked admin and security role. How to view errorlog.txt file?

Comment: @Ajaii You need to isolate the issue on the ML side first. Confirm that a user with the role you are mapping to LDAP is capable of accessing the ML endpoint directly. The log is in `Marklogic\Data\Logs\ErrorLog.txt`.

Comment: @wst: Since I am not using the licensed server. I couldn't generate a ticket and send the problem to ML. I deleted all the user and created users from the beginning. I can able to login all the users except mine.

Comment: @Ajaii Please confirm that you are connecting directly to the ML REST endpoint using a ML user credentials (i.e.: *not* LDAP).